# how to change background image periodically in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am new in SharePoint, and I want to make SharePoint site background changes automatically as per calendar occasions,,,

for Example:: in seasons year round (summer, winter, spring and autumn) each season changes background.

by the way I tried to change the theme with built in SharePoint theme but it dose not change any thing.

so please help me to make this with simple steps ,,,,

Answer (score 0):

you can just use javascript for this. The output of SharePoint is html/javascript so you should not handle this any different than another CMS/website.

In your document.ready or document.load event call this function:

**Just watching the month:**

```
function setBGBySeason() {
        var date = new Date();
        month = date.getMonth();

        winter = '12,1,2,';
        spring = '3,4,5,';
        summer = '6,7,8,';
        fall = '9,10,11,';

        season = 'unknown';

        if (winter.indexOf(month) != -1) {
            season = 'winter';
            bgcolor = "#003399";
        } else if (spring.indexOf(month) != -1) {
            season = 'spring';
            bgcolor = "#ffffcc";
        } else if (summer.indexOf(month) != -1) {
            season = 'summer';
            bgcolor = "#ffff00";
        } else if (fall.indexOf(month) != -1) {
            season = 'fall';
            bgcolor = "#f2ffe6";
        }

        document.body.style.background = bgcolor;
        console.log(season);
    }
```

**Watching the complete date:**

```
var dates = {
convert:function(d) {
    // Converts the date in d to a date-object. The input can be:
    //   a date object: returned without modification
    //  an array      : Interpreted as [year,month,day]. NOTE: month is 0-11.
    //   a number     : Interpreted as number of milliseconds
    //                  since 1 Jan 1970 (a timestamp) 
    //   a string     : Any format supported by the javascript engine, like
    //                  "YYYY/MM/DD", "MM/DD/YYYY", "Jan 31 2009" etc.
    //  an object     : Interpreted as an object with year, month and date
    //                  attributes.  **NOTE** month is 0-11.
    return (
        d.constructor === Date ? d :
        d.constructor === Array ? new Date(d[0],d[1],d[2]) :
        d.constructor === Number ? new Date(d) :
        d.constructor === String ? new Date(d) :
        typeof d === "object" ? new Date(d.year,d.month,d.date) :
        NaN
    );
},
compare:function(a,b) {
    // Compare two dates (could be of any type supported by the convert
    // function above) and returns:
    //  -1 : if a < b
    //   0 : if a = b
    //   1 : if a > b
    // NaN : if a or b is an illegal date
    // NOTE: The code inside isFinite does an assignment (=).
    return (
        isFinite(a=this.convert(a).valueOf()) &&
        isFinite(b=this.convert(b).valueOf()) ?
        (a>b)-(a<b) :
        NaN
    );
},
inRange:function(d,start,end) {
    // Checks if date in d is between dates in start and end.
    // Returns a boolean or NaN:
    //    true  : if d is between start and end (inclusive)
    //    false : if d is before start or after end
    //    NaN   : if one or more of the dates is illegal.
    // NOTE: The code inside isFinite does an assignment (=).
   return (
        isFinite(d=this.convert(d).valueOf()) &&
        isFinite(start=this.convert(start).valueOf()) &&
        isFinite(end=this.convert(end).valueOf()) ?
        start <= d && d <= end :
        NaN
        );
    }
}

function setBGBySeason() {
    var date = new Date();
    var year = date.getFullYear();

    var springStart = new Date(year + "-03-21");
    var summerStart = new Date(year + "-06-21");
    var fallStart = new Date(year + "-09-21");
    var winterStart = new Date(year + "-12-21");

    var season = "unknown";
    var bgcolor = "white";

    if(dates.inRange(date, springStart, summerStart)){
        season = 'Spring';
        bgcolor = "#ffffcc";
    }else if(dates.inRange(date, summerStart, fallStart)){
        season = 'Summer';
        bgcolor = "#ffff00";
    }else if(dates.inRange(date, fallStart, winterStart)){
        season = 'Fall';
        bgcolor = "#f2ffe6";
    }else if(dates.inRange(date, winterStart, springStart)){
        season = 'Winter';
        bgcolor = "#003399";
    }

    document.body.style.background = bgcolor;
    console.log(season);
}
```

So what is happening:

- Getting the date of today
- Retrieving the month of the date
- Depending on the month we can identify the season
- Setting a color for each season
- Using document.body.style.background, we set the color of the
  background

PS: I found the dates object on stackoverflow, didn't wrote it myself but seems to work like it should

Comment: thanks a lot ,, but i want to change _background image_ between specific dates like ( spring _from 21-Mar till 21-Jun)

Comment: there is no way to do it in CSS file ,,,,,

Comment: there is no way to do it in CSS file ,,,,,

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to do it in CSS file ,,,,,

Comment: no, you need javascripts to get the dates and to the comparisons